# Reading WCF behavior elements from config file programmticlally when exposing self-hosted service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, configuration, self-hosting

I have this configuration in my app.config:

```
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>



<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I want to expose this service programmatically from my desktop app:

I define the host instance:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyType), new Uri("http://" + hostName + ":" + port + "/MyName"));
```

Then I add the endpoint with it's binding:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding("myBinding");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyInterface), binding, "MyName");
```

**Now, I want to replace the folowing code with some code that reads the behavior named *myBehavior* from the config file, and not hard-coding the behavior options.**

```
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true };    
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);   
// Enable exeption details
ServiceDebugBehavior sdb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
```

Then, I can open the host.

```
host.Open();
```

*** EDIT ***

**Configuring Services Using Configuration Files**

You shouldn't need this way, you should make the host takes its configuration automagically from the config file, and not giving them manually, read [this article (Configuring Services Using Configuration Files)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx), it will help you, I have hosted my service in a single line in C# and few ones in config.

[This is a second article about (Configuring WCF Services in Code)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277.aspx),
 my fault is that i was trying to mix the two ways!

I will add this as an answer.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons not to use a config file, i.e retrieving addresses and such from an external source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to open the configuration file by either using

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

or

```
var map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = "app.config";
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Then you read the behaviors:

```
var bindings = BindingsSection.GetSection(config);
var group = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);
foreach (var behavior in group.Behaviors.ServiceBehaviors)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("BEHAVIOR: {0}", behavior);
}
```

Note that these are of type `System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceBehaviorElement`, so not quite what you want yet.

If you don't mind using a private APIs, you can call the protected method `BehaviorExtensionElement.CreateBehavior()` via reflection:

```
foreach (BehaviorExtensionElement bxe in behavior)
{
    var createBeh = typeof(BehaviorExtensionElement).GetMethod(
        "CreateBehavior", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    IServiceBehavior b = (IServiceBehavior)createBeh.Invoke(bxe, new object[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("BEHAVIOR: {0}", b);
    host.Description.Behaviors.Add (b);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Configuring Services Using Configuration Files**

You shouldn't need this way, you should make the host takes its configuration automagically from the config file, and not giving them manually, read [this article (Configuring Services Using Configuration Files)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733932.aspx), it will help you, I have hosted my service in a single line in C# and few ones in config.

[This is a second article about (Configuring WCF Services in Code)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205277.aspx),
 my fault is that i was trying to mix the two ways!

Comment: Unless you don't want to use default config files

Answer (score 1):

While this is an old question, I had problems finding what I needed elsewhere, so for future reference here is my solution.

```
var behaviorSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/behaviors") as BehaviorsSection;
if (behaviorSection != null)
{
                // for each behavior, check for client and server certificates
    foreach (EndpointBehaviorElement behavior in behaviorSection.EndpointBehaviors)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInformation pi in behavior.ElementInformation.Properties)
        {
            if (pi.Type == typeof(ClientCredentialsElement))
            {
                var clientCredentials = pi.Value as ClientCredentialsElement;
                var clientCert = clientCredentials.ClientCertificate;
                            // TODO: Add code...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`ConfigurationManager.Open...Configuration()` does not work well with web projects, so manually getting section and casting it is simpler.

If you are really insistent on letting the `System.ServiceModel` do the config reading for you it is possible to do something like this:

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"), "web.config"); // the root web.config  
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var group = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(config);

foreach (EndpointBehaviorElement item in group.Behaviors.EndpointBehaviors)
{
    // TODO: add code...
}
```

The 2nd method uses `HttpContext.Current`, and as we all know `HttpContext.Current` is horrible when doing unit tests.